# Move record from one grid to another (Genexus x evo 1 )

Tags: genexus

I'm currently working with GeneXus X Evolution 1 in a windows form application.

I can't seem to find the correct way to move selected records from one grid to another.

All I can do is move the selected record in the first grid to the first row of the second grid.

This is what I see when I select the first record:

[image: Select first record]

And this when the second one is selected:

[image: When i select the second record or any other]

My code looks like:

```
Event &LineaSeleccionadaGrilla.Click
    if &LineaSeleccionadaGrilla = true
        &ProdSelGrilla = ''
        &ProdSelGrilla = ProdId 
        &i = &i + 1 
        if &i <= rows(&ArregloProdSel())
            &ArregloProdSel(&i,1) = &ProdSelGrilla
            &ProdidSeleccion.AddItem(str(&i),&ArregloProdSel(&i,1) ) 
        endif
        grillafinal.Refresh()
    endif       
EndEvent

Event grillafinal.Load // esto carga la grilla
    &ProdIdFinal = &ProdSelGrilla
EndEvent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in the `grillafinal.Load` event, you are loading only the last selected record.

Assuming `&ArregloProdSel` is a collection of `ProdId` (don't know why it is a matrix and not just an array, though), your `grillafinal.Load` event should look something like this:

```
Event grillafinal.Load
    for &j = 1 to rows(&ArregloProdSel())
        &ProdIdFinal = &ArregloProdSel(&j,1)
        Load
    endfor
EndEvent
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcos, I added your suggestion to the code, the compiler shows no error but the program crashes as it loads. I get the following error; "System.IndexOutOfRangeException".

Comment: I ´ve found the problem.  &ProdIdFinal = &ArregloProdSel(&i,1). The &i must be replaced with &j. Thanks marcos!